# Custom Map ,there is no latLng ,how to add marker?

Tags: jvectormap

$(function(){
          var map,
              markerIndex = 0,
              markersCoords = {};

```
      map = new jvm.WorldMap({
          map: 'jilin',
          markerStyle: {
            initial: {
              fill: 'red'
            }
          },
          container: $('#world-map-gdp')
      });

      map.container.click(function(e){
          var latLng = map.pointToLatLng(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        alert(latLng);

      });
      $('.jvectormap-zoomin').click(); //放大  
    });
```

I use svg produced a Jilin Province Map of China.
I want to add several markers in the map
But I can not get latLng ，And I don't know why ? 
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/) from the official site on dealing with markers for maps converted from SVG.

Comment: @Dean Please don't forget to mark the question as answered if some answer helped you to resolve your issue.

Comment: When loading map display name, rather than when mouse over
.I want to disply the name,how can I make this ?

Comment: Use the method "onRegionLabelShow" from WorldMap class. Here: http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/